# Plotting power vs. effect size using R pwr package

Tags: r, plot

I can successfully create plots of power vs. sample size in R using the pwr package. Example code below.

```
library(pwr)
library(tidyverse)

plot.out <- pwr.t2n.test(n1=30, n2=30, d=0.5, alternative="two.sided")

#See output in link below
plot(plot.out)
```

[plot() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzc53.png)

I would like to create a similar plot -- a **two-sample t-test** in which **effect size is on the y-axis and power is on the x-axis**, with **fixed sample sizes**.

Is there a way to do this using pwr and/or the plot function? Or would I have to unlist the plot.out object and use it somehow?

I'm still new to power curves in R. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code below the power is computed in a loop on effect size `d_seq`. Then the power `d` is extracted from the results list, a data.frame is created and plotted.

```
library(pwr)
library(ggplot2)

d_seq <- seq(0, 2, by = 0.1)
pwr_list <- lapply(d_seq, function(d){
  pwr.t2n.test(n1 = 30, n2 = 30, 
               d = d,
               power = NULL,
               sig.level = 0.05, 
               alternative = "two.sided")
})
pwr <- sapply(pwr_list, '[[', 'power')

dfpwr <- data.frame(power = pwr, effect.size = d_seq)

ggplot(dfpwr, aes(effect.size, power)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, colour = "black") +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("effect size") +
  ylab(expression("test power =" ~ 1 - beta))
```

[image]

---

To draw a line where power is 80% and get the effect size, first compute the effect size from the `pwr` vector by linear interpolation.

```
pwr80 <- approx(x = pwr, y = d_seq, xout = 0.8)
```

Now create a label for `geom_text` and plot it.

```
lbl80 <- paste("Power = 80%\n")
lbl80 <- paste(lbl80, "Effect size =", round(pwr80$y, 2))

ggplot(dfpwr, aes(effect.size, power)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, colour = "black") +
  geom_line(size = 0.5, colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_text(x = pwr80$y, y = pwr80$x, 
            label = lbl80,
            hjust = 1, vjust = -1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("effect size") +
  ylab(expression("test power =" ~ 1 - beta))
```

[image]

To also draw a vertical line, add

```
geom_vline(xintercept = pwr80$y, linetype = "dotted")
```

Comment: Brilliant! And I'm thinking I can use coord_flip() to flip the axes as needed. One final question: How could I add a line for the optimal effect size where power = 0.80? I know I can put a geom_vline or geom_hline set at 0.80, but specifically to show and label the optimal effect size at 80% power.

Comment: This is phenomenal. Thank you so much for your assistance, Rui.